# Combine options with arguments getopt

Tags: c, linux, command-line, gnu, getopt

hello i am writing a program that takes in multiple options from the command line in c. these are some of the options:

```
-l   counts number of lines in file
-w   counts words in file
-c   counts characters in file
```

so to make them work, you could do:

```
./program -l file.txt
./program -w file.txt
./program -c file.txt
```

however i want to combine them so that multiple options still do as they should. e.g.:

```
./program -lwc file.txt
```

will count lines, words, AND files,

```
./program -lw file.txt
```

will count lines AND words,

```
./program -cl file.txt
```

will count characters AND lines, etc. i just cant figure out how to do this. this is my code for the arguments:

```
while ( ( c = getopt( argc, argv, "c:w:l:" ) ) != -1 ) { /* get options */
    switch ( c ) {
        case 'c':
            cflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'w':
            wflag = 2;
            break;
        case 'l':
            lflag = 3;
            break;
    }   
}
```

is it simply changing options around but it still doesnt work. with the code i have now, combining two options results in a segment fault. any help is appreciated

Comment: You should make the options not take an argument and then read the file-name when the option-processing is done (when `getopt` returns `-1`). Use `optind` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jens Gustedt said: remove the colons from the options to make them not take an argument. Then, when option-processing is done (i.e. `getopt` returned `-1`), check if `optind` is less than `argc` meaning there was an extra argument (your file-name). Like this:

```
/* after the while-loop */
if(optind < argc){
    fileName = argv[optind];
    optind++;
}else{
    perror("No file specified");
    return -1;
}
```

When `getopt` is done `optind` points to the first entry in `argv` that wasn't processed by `getopt`.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` in the `getopt` format are for options with arguments. Delete them.